# kafka Consumer is not accepting the message in the kafka server

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have configured some topics in both producer and consumer side. kafka operations is working fine. But after some weeks nearly 6 or 7 weeks the message is pushing by the producer and am able to do see that messages in kafka logs.

My consumer is not able to accept that. To solve this issue i need to change the topics in both producer and consumer sides. Without doing this not able to solve this issue.

also i have added these may properties as well

```
spring.kafka.listener.missing-topics-fatal=false

spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest

spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=manual

spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false

spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=\*
```

i have tried by changing the kafka configurations

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerCreditNotApproval {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${rom.manualTask.creditNot.approval.kafka.topic}", groupId = "${rom.manualTask.kafka.groupId}")
    public void listen(String message,Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        logger.info("Received Message...: " + message);
        logger.info("Kafka Ip!!!!!!!!!!!"+kafkaIp);
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        logger.info("@creditNot.approval.kafka!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String transactionId = null;
        Map<String, Object> readValue = null;
        try {
            readValue = mapper.readValue(message, Map.class);
            transactionId = String.valueOf(readValue.get("requestKey"));
            logger.info("Map data: " + readValue);
            service.processTransaction(transactionId, readValue);
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            logger.error("JsonMappingException occured:", e);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            logger.error("JsonProcessingException occured:", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception occured:", e);
        }
    }
}
```

without changing the topics in both